# Schema.org Event allowed and sensefull inside Article?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Ist it allowed and does it make sense to put an `Event` inside an `Article`?
Or does it make more sense to wrap the full `Article` as `Event`?

Example:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
...
<div itemprop="articleBody">
    <p>
        Having largely succeeded in stopping a rout of
        Libya's rebels, the inchoate coalition attacking
        Col. Muammar el-Qaddafi's forces remains divided
        over the ultimate goal — and exit strategy —
        of what officials acknowledged Thursday would be
        a military campaign that could last for weeks.
    </p>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EducationEvent">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="This is the Eventdescription">
        <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2017-02-01T00:00">
        <meta itemprop="endDate" content="2017-02-01T00:00">
        <meta itemprop="duration" content="0000-00-00T08:00">
        <link itemprop="url" content="http://www.google.com" rel="author"/>
        <a itemprop="url" href="www.google.com"><span itemprop="name" style="display:block;"><strong>Meine Schulung</strong></span></a>
        <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="name" style="display:block;"><strong>Schulung GmbH</strong></span>
            <span itemprop="streetAddress" style="display:block;">myStreet</span>
            <div>
                <span itemprop="addressLocality" style="display:block;">Berlin</span>,
                <span itemprop="addressRegion"style="display:block;">Berlin</span>
            </div>
            <span itemprop="postalCode"style="display:block;">1036723</span>
            <span itemprop="addressCountry"style="display:block;">Germany</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t use a property (in `itemprop`), it doesn’t matter how you nest Microdata items.

As you don’t use a property, your `Article` and your `EducationEvent` are not related/connected in any way.

It’s not clear to me what their relationship should be in your case. If, for example, you would write an `Article` about an `EducationEvent`, you could use the [`about` property](http://schema.org/about):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EducationEvent">
  </div>
</div>
```